# When Japanese characters are output to standard output with Azure Functions, the characters are garbled with Application Insight. RRS feed

Tags: azure-functions

When Japanese characters are output to standard output by System.out .print in Azure Functions (Java), the characters are garbled in Application Insight.

Is there a way to display the message in Application Insight without garbled characters?

The JVM options specify:

JAVA_OPTS -Dfile.encoding=utf-8

```java
    @FunctionName("HttpExample")
    public HttpResponseMessage run(
            @HttpTrigger(
                    name = "req",
                    methods = {HttpMethod.GET, HttpMethod.POST},
                    authLevel = AuthorizationLevel.ANONYMOUS) HttpRequestMessage<Optional<String>> request,
            final ExecutionContext context) {
        context.getLogger().info("Java HTTP trigger processed a request.");

        System.out.println("日本語表示");

        // Parse query parameter
        final String query = request.getQueryParameters().get("name");
        final String name = request.getBody().orElse(query);

        log.info("Get query : " + query);
        log.info("Get name : " + name);

        if (name == null) {
            return request.createResponseBuilder(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body("Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body").build();
        } else {
            return request.createResponseBuilder(HttpStatus.OK).body("Hello, " + name).build();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide the sentences? I use "日本語テキスト", but there are no garbled characters in Application Insights.

Comment: I have listed the method in question.

Comment: We generally do not use the system console to output information inside azure functions. Do you have any reason why `System.out.println()` must be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to display the message in Application Insight without
> garbled characters?

For azure function, please do not use System.out.println() to print information when printing output. Below can display the message in Application Insight without garbled characters:

```
String str = "日本語表示";
context.getLogger().info(str);
```

[image]